# ASP.NET core MVC <form method="post"> передаёт пустой конструктор в ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть Index.cshtml

```cshtml
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@model Xy;
@*...*@
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="x" value="@Model.x" />
        <input type="number" name="y" step="0.01"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn"/>
    </form>
```

И два IActionResult в HomeController:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            float x = (float)Round(new Random().NextDouble()*24+1,2);
            return View(new Xy(x));
        }

[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Xy Answer)
        {
            //...
        }
```

И, соответственно, сам класс Xy:

```cs
public class Xy
    {
        public float x;
        public float? y;

        public Xy()
        {
            x = float.NaN;
            y = null;
        }

        public Xy(float X, float? Y = null)
        {
            x = X;
            y = Y;
        }
    }
```

Почему при нажатии на кнопку, в `Index(Xy Answer)` передаётся пустой `Xy()`? То есть, с `x` = `NaN` и `y` = `null`, когда `x` должен быть равен @Model.x, а `y` числу в поле `<input type="number" name="y" step="0.01"/>`?

Кроме минимизации кода (здесь я привёл именно минимизированный код), я пробовал заменить "name" на "asp-for" и "asp-form" – не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в непонимании отличия полей от параметров. Чтобы всё работало, в классе нужно объявить именно параметры, а не поля – то есть, вместо

```cs
public float x;
public float? y;
```

должно быть

```cs
public float x { get; set; }
public float? y { get; set; }
```